# How to position div underneath dynamic ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a ul/li which is only visible with onkeyup event. 
If an input field is empty the ul/li disappears (hide), all is done with plain JavaScript and Jquery.
The problem is that I want to position a div underneath the ul/li (when it is visible).
How do I do that? Should I use CSS like position:absolute/relative/fixed (which didn't work so far), or do I have to use JavaScript for this?

Comment: Can you provide some code and html markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options with pure CSS:

1) Use `absolute` position.

2) Give parent element `relative` position and your div (child) `absolute` position so that child does not escape out of parent. Finally use `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` properties to position element exactly where you want.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the ul and div and then show/hide the wrapper instead of the ul:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <ul> <li> ... </li> </ul>
   <div>the div you want below the ul</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the "underneath" div should also be invisible until the `onkeyup` even occurs, toggle it's visibility in the same way that you toggle the `ul`.

If the "underneath" div should always be visible, you can use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none` on the ul. This will make the ul invisible, but will preserve its position in the page flow.

Answer (score 1):

It have to work with absolute positioning, but take care to have both in the same parent with position relative or absolute, this is very important.